# Powershell script monitor website that requires login?

Tags: asp.net, powershell, authentication, alert, monitoring

I'm somewhat new to PowerShell, but can do some things. I have to monitor a website that's hosted on a 2008r2 server. I've found scripts online that might work for a regular site.
In my case I need to monitor a website that requires user authentication from a domain user and I have an account I can use, although encrypting the creds would be great!
The next trick which I haven't figure out how to do is after a user logs into the website they are on a landing page. Next they have to click a tab/link at the top of the page to get to the web page which is actually failing. It's a homegrown app that was just developed. It appears like it's an asp type error, but I need to monitor further to then gather data to troubleshoot. The web group "can't assist" with this it seems....
I'm enjoying learning anyway, can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried and your code that isn't working?

Comment: It seems to me Coded UI testing would be ideal for this use case. http://uiautomation.codeplex.com/

Comment: I haven't been able to get anything together that works at all to login to the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use curl.exe for Windows with Powershell (http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

I used curl a lot to monitor sites with a POST of credentials etc.

For example:

`curl.exe http://username:password@api.somesite.com/test/blah?something=123`

Please read through this: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html to get an idea of all the possible options.